# angularjs $http params with slash

Tags: angularjs, slim

I am using angularjs with slim php and I have a GET action in slim which

```
action/param1/param2
```

Then in my angularJS

```
$http({
 url: 'action',
method: 'GET',
params:{param1: param1, param2: param2}
}).success();
```

It return error in console with using ? and &, but I need it get with slash between params

```
http://xxxxxx/action?param=aaa&param2=bbb
```

What I have tried, I change the $http params to below and it works

```
 url: 'action/' + param1 + '/' + param2
```

Ok, my question is, is there any better solution compare to mine?  because I feel mine stupid.

Comment: I dont think there is, bc your `params` aren't really params, they are part of your resource, so you need to put them in `url`

Comment: I agree with Nix. Have you considered wrapping `$http` in a service, which could be passed the URL and params, and format the request before sending?

Comment: You're doing it right.

Comment: @AlexOsborn Yes, I will move the $http to a shared service.

Answer (score 0):

Use [$resource](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource) instead:

```
var myResource = $resource('action/:foo/:bar', {},
                           { get: { method: 'GET' } }
                          );
myResource.get({foo:1, bar:2});
```

Will yield a call to:

http://yourserver.com/action/1/2

Comment: Any idea how to do it with $http?

Comment: Build the http url manually `"http://yourserver.com/action/" + param1 + '/' + param2`